# Basic division and multiplication

Tags: arithmetic, axioms

We know that 2 x 2 /2 can be solved by removing '2' from the denominator and numerator, we can't do the same if the operation was addition, These "rules" have been established based on the understanding of these operations and how these interact with each other.

Up until now, I've just been accepting it as a rule, but this causes a lot of discomforts while doing math.

I generally get good grades in math, but that's only by following these rules and patterns but there is no genuine understanding as to why we can remove "2" from the numerator and denominator in 2 x 2 /2 but we cannot in 2 + 2/2.

Secondly, 2 x 2 / 2 can be solved by removing "2" from the numerator and the denominator and it gives the same result as 4/2, how?.
Is it an axiom?

I hope to gain an intuition for the above concepts, so I can be free from my long-held guilt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{2\times 2}{2}=2\times 2\times \frac12$$

and by associative property, which is an axiom we have that

$$(2\times 2)\times \frac12=4\times \frac12=2$$

$$2\times \left(2\times \frac12\right)=2\times 1=2$$

are two equivalent way to simplify the expression.

Comment: Note that the first line is based (I think) on $defining$ division by $x$ as multiplication by the reciprocal of $x$.

Comment: @timtfj Yes of course my discussion is not fully axiomatic, my aim was to pint out that the "cancellation step" can be done in both ways according to the associative law.

Comment: Sure. My comment was to reassure the OP that the division step is accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Before 'nailing down' multiplication and division, the first step is be totally comfortable with one concept - 'adding up' positive numbers. As an intuitive map for images held in the brain, you can take your unit of measure to be '$1$ Apple Pie' or ''$1$ Meter'.

If you have '$1$ Apple Pie' you can certainly imagine having one in the left hand and one in the right hand and combining them. If we use the notation [AP] for this unit,

$\tag 1 1 \text{ [AP]} + 1 \text{ [AP]} = (1 + 1) \text{ [AP]} = 2 \text{ [AP]}$

Notice that we can now begin to understand multiplication with an integer as 'repeated addition' notation:

$\tag 2 2 \times  1 \text{ [AP]} = 1 \text{ [AP]} + 1 \text{ [AP]}  = (2 \times 1)\text{ [AP]}$

Now what is, say, $\frac{1}{4} \text{ [AP]}$? This looks good

$\tag 3 4 \times \frac{1}{4} \text{ [AP]} = 1\text{[AP]}$

This fractional notation, once you think of what we are trying to represent, is a marvelous notation.

Addition is about combining quantities. So $2\text{[AP]} + 1\text{[AP]} = 3\text{[AP]}$.

Now the OP was wondering about $2 + 2/2$, and it might be useful for them to review [mixed number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers) notation. But

$\tag 4 \frac{2}{2} = 2 \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$

(right - combining half a pie with half a pie is a full pie)

So $2 + 2/2 = 3$.

Also, $2 \times 2/2 = \frac{2}{2} + \frac{2}{2} = (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}) = 1 + 1 = 2$

After the OP is totally comfortable with these ideas and can use them without a second thought, they can proceed to understanding multiplication and division.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer here. Really develops intuition as opposed to some of the more formal answers here.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the $2$ from the numerator and denominator what you are really doing is multiplying the fraction by $1$ in the form $$\dfrac {\dfrac{ \ 1\ }{\ 2\ }}{\dfrac{ \ 1\ }{\ 2\ }}$$
You can do the same with $2+\frac 22$, which becomes $2+\frac 11=3$.  When you multiply $2$ by $\frac 12$ you get $1$, not nothing.  In multiplication just removing it works because $1$ is the multiplicative identity, but it is a bad idea to think of it as removing.  That will lead to errors like the one you cite.

Answer (score 0):

> $\dfrac {2 \times 2}{ 2 }$ can be solved by removing $2$ from the numerator and the denominator and it gives the same result as $\dfrac 4 2$, how? Is it an axiom?

No, it is not an axiom. But, as for every rule for operating with numbers, it is obviously justified by axioms.

Regarding the [rationals (i.e. *fractions*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) they are an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).

Regarding *division*, the axioms state that :

> If $a \ne 0$, then the equation $a \cdot x = b$ has a unique solution : $x = \dfrac b a = b \cdot a^{−1}$.

Thus, $a^{−1}$ is the [*multiplicative inverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Inverse) of $a$.

We have :

> $\dfrac {a \cdot a} a = (a \cdot a) \cdot a^{−1}$.

By [Associativity of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) we have that :

> $(a \cdot a) \cdot a^{−1} = a \cdot (a \cdot a^{−1})$.

But $(a \cdot a^{−1})=1$ and again by axiom :

> $a \cdot 1=a$.

Putting all together, we get :

> $\dfrac {a \cdot a} a = a$.

---

At an "intuitive level" it is simply a metter of multipling and dividing quantities.

We multiply *two* by *two* the get *four* and then we divide *four* by *two*, getting *two*.

In real life applications of numerical oeprations we do not "cancel" anything.

Comment: But, division is taught as : if a / b then "b" is the number which tells a person how many equal parts have to be made of that number "a" and the answers gives us the value of one such part.  You put it as if it din't have any intuition or reason behind it, why is division the inverse of multiplication, am i suppose to just accept it?

Comment: @MinigameZmore Division is DEFINED to be the inverse of multiplication. Of course you have to accept it. That's like arguing about the intuition as to why a certain word has a certain meaning. As humans, we've chosen for it to have that meaning. However, I don't think this formal of an answer is really going to help you, since your confusion is clearly at a more basic level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how advanced in mathematics you are so this is going to be the real simple explanation.

The fraction bar is notation for division. $\frac{3}{4}$ represents the  number that is defined as the result of the operation $ 3\div 4.$

Therefore $$ \frac{2}{2} = 1$$ because $2 \div 2 = 1.$
In your case

$$ 2 \times \frac{2}{2} = 2 \times 1 = 2$$
So it looks like we just "removed" the two's. This only works because we end up by multiplying by $1$ so it is in general best not to talk about it like that.

This obviously doesn't work for addition

$$ 2 + \frac{2}{2} = 2 + 1 = 3.$$

Also $$ \frac{4}{2} = 4 \div 2 = 2 \quad \text{ so } \quad  2 \times \frac{2}{2} = \frac{4}{2}.$$

Comment: Suppose, we have 2 + 2/2 in order to remove the two in the denominator we have to divide both the two's in the numerator, but in the case of multiplication 2 x 2 /2 we just need to remove one "2" from the numerator to eliminate the denominator, why does that happen?

Comment: When you write 2 + 2/2 do you mean $\frac{2+2}{2}$ or $2 +\frac{2}{2}$.  Also what do you mean by removing a 2. Could you write out how you would solve the problem so I can see what you're doing ? To write fractions use the \frac{}{} command and write \$ around your equations.